# How to start koin from another class instead of Application class

Tags: android, koin

I am creating an app as library. The main app in which library has to be integrated  has an Application class, so I can't add Application class in my library app. I have found that koin has to be started from Application class. Can I call startKoin from another class?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `KoinApplication` which does not share the global koin context. You also don't need to initialize this inside an `Application` class. This instance can then be used in your own implementation of `KoinComponent`.

You can find a detailed description here:

https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/start-koin?id=koin-context-isolation

Answer (score 0):

If you purpose is to inject library dependencies to your app, you can have your library expose set of modules that can be referred from you app and be initialised while starting Koin.

For example:

In library, you have a public module as libraryModule:

```
val libraryModule = module{
    single{
        ObjectA()
    }
}
```

Now, when you include your library in your app module, you would be able use it as:

```
class MyApplication : Application{

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeKoinDI()
    }


    private fun initializeKoinDI() {
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)
            modules(listOf(appModule1, appModule2, libraryModule))
        }
    }
}
```